# Get sum of records if value exists consider as 1 not exact value

Tags: mysql

[image]

I need "Open" as 2 and click as 1 But now I'm getting like open as 5 and click as 2

```
"SELECT 
COALESCE(sum(requested),0) as requested,
COALESCE(sum(processed),0) as processed,
COALESCE(sum(open),0) as open,
COALESCE(sum(click),0) as click,
COALESCE(sum(dropped),0) as dropped,
COALESCE(sum(delivered),0) as delivered,
COALESCE(sum(spamreport),0) as spamreport,
COALESCE(sum(deferred),0) as deferred,
COALESCE(sum(bounce),0) as bounce,
COALESCE(sum(unsubscribe),0) as unsubscribe
FROM CAMPAIGN_REPORTS WHERE _kftCampaingID='".$campaignId."'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum()` works as expected. If you wish to treat anything above 0 as 1, then write if condition like below. That being said, `coalesce` looks redundant here then.

```
sum(if(open is not null and open > 0, 1, 0)),
sum(if(click is not null and click > 0, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans @nice_dev
Same as I have found another solution also . 

  COALESCE(sum(case when open > 0 then 1 else 0 end),0) as open,
   COALESCE(sum(case when click > 0 then 1 else 0 end),0) as click,

Comment: @Maheskumar Sure, use whatever you are comfortable with. IMO, using case for a single condition seems like an overkill.